# STATISTICS not allowed in the Attribute Table

Tags: arcgis-10.1, attribute-table, statistics

I created a shapefile, calculated geometry then went to grab the stats, the statistics was ghosted, not allowing me to grab those numbers.  I am using 10.1 ArcView.

I deleted the field and created a new field in ArcCatalog but no luck, same results.  Not sure why that is happening.

Some help, please.

Comment: I just tested this using ArcGIS 10.1 and it seemed to work fine.  When you say you used "Catalog" do you mean the "Catalog window" or "ArcCatalog".  I used and would recommend using the "Catalog window".  Also you have a tag saying arcgis-10.0 yet you say you are using 10.1 so can you update that, please?

Comment: No, I used Arc Catalog, not the window.  I will try that method-------- //  

I used the Catalog Window with same results.

Comment: Perhaps you can list your precise steps in more detail to ensure that I and others can follow your procedure precisely.  These detailed steps should include your ArcGIS version (and any service pack), Windows version (and any service packs), as well as the location of the shapefile (is it perhaps on a shared drive).

Comment: Do any of the geometries contains 0 values ?

Comment: I did Double in my test and thought after reading your comment that the cause must have been letting it default to Short Integer - but I just tested that and Statistics remained available after Calculate Geometry.  In any event be sure to Answer your own Question when you can so that it can act as something for anyone else encountering it to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it - while creating the ADD FIELD.. after naming it, I did DOUBLE and 8 / 2 in the precision field. That fixed the problem. Thanks